# Qual é o sentido de usar scripts em links?

Tags: javascript, html

Recentemente vi no site do [W3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_a_href_script) a possibilidade de executar códigos em JavaScript em links, colocando os scripts dentro do atributo `href`:

```
<a href="javascript:alert('Hello World!');">Execute JavaScript</a>
```

Por que isso existe, tem algum motivo para isso ainda funcionar?

Comment: Por que não deveria existir?

Comment: O atributo `href` (Hypertext Reference ou referência para hipertexto) é usado com o objetivo de especificar uma URL. Não faz sentido colocar scripts (códigos que vão ser executados) no atributo `href` destinado a endereços (pelo menos na minha perspectiva já que quebraria o significado do atributo `href`).

Comment: Vou tentar de novo: **Por que** não deveria existir? Precisa dar um motivo, não fazer uma especulação. O problema da pergunta é justamente especular que isso não deveria existir. Sem saber a sua motivação da pergunta, ela não tem sentido. Daí veio uma resposta que é só uma crença. Tanto em perguntas quanto respostas, crenças não ajudam muito.

Comment: @Maniero, Justamente por isso eu pergunto do **Porque** e se existe algum **Motivo** para os scripts funcionarem em links. Em relação a sua pergunta **Por que não deveria existir?** é uma pergunta reversa já que eu pergunto do "porque isso existe", mas na minha visão é por conta de semântica mesmo!

Comment: Então eu vou responder, porque já tem resposta que nem responde e tem positivos. Vamos ver se você realmente quer saber o porquê ou partiu de uma premissa errada.

Comment: Na verdade lendo o seu comentário em uma resposta mostra que não quer saber o porquê, sem explicar o motivo real porque quer saber isso não dá para responder, as duas respostas dadas não respondem o que quer saber ou o porquê disso existir, pior é uma delas nem passar perto e ter 2 positivos. Vou apenas resumir aqui o motivo de isso existir: não existe motivo para não existir. Se existe em outros lugares porque esse lugar deveria ser especial? E se você precisar fazer uso criativo disso?

Comment: Se a pergunta é sobre por que funciona colocar código JavaScript no `href` (qualquer código, não necessariamente alert), sugiro mudar o exemplo para um código genérico qualquer, sem o alert. Digo isso porque as respostas abaixo focaram mais no alert do que no porquê (na verdade nenhuma respondeu porque é possível, mas talvez seja porque o alert acabou "desviando a atenção" e se tornando o foco da pergunta, quando na verdade ele é só parte de um exemplo qualquer) - a propósito, o seu exemplo funciona sim (testei no Chrome)

Comment: @hkotsubo, sim funciona (menos aqui no stackoverflow, testei e não funcionou)

Comment: De qualquer forma, se vc quer saber por que é possível rodar js no href, sugiro mudar o título da pergunta. "*Por que existe?*" é uma coisa, "*faz sentido?*" é outra (e as respostas abaixo focam no "faz sentido" e nem mencionam nada sobre o "por que existe", daí a confusão)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> *Por que isso existe, tem algum motivo para isso ainda funcionar?*

Vamos por partes...

---

### *URI Schemes*

O valor `javascript:código JavaScript` é uma URI que usa o *URI Scheme* `javascript`. Basicamente, existem vários *schemes* diferentes (por exemplo, em uma URL como `http://www.abc.com`, o `http` é o *scheme*, mas há outros que não são necessariamente usados para URL's, como `mailto`, `file`, `maps`, entre outros - [a lista é imensa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_URI_schemes)).

No *link* do parágrafo anterior, o *scheme* `javascript` é listado como "*Unofficial but common*" (ou seja, não é oficialmente reconhecido pela IANA, cuja lista oficial é [esta](https://www.iana.org/assignments/uri-schemes/uri-schemes.xhtml)), mas ainda sim existe e é suportado pelos *browsers* ([veja aqui o *draft*](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-hoehrmann-javascript-scheme-03) que define este *scheme*).

E onde eu posso colocar um *URI Scheme* em um documento HTML? Basicamente, em qualquer atributo [desta lista](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/index/attributes.html) cujo tipo seja `URI`. Veja que o `a[href]` é um desses cujo tipo é `URI`, mas também existem outros, como o `img[src]`, `body[background]`, `form[action]` e muitos outros (e além destes, também posso colocar código JavaScript nos [atributos relacionados a eventos](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/scripts.html#h-18.2.3), como `onclick`, `onload`, etc - a diferença é que estes só podem ter código, enquanto os outros atributos já citados podem ter qualquer URI válida).

Isso não quer dizer que sempre vai funcionar com todos, claro. Por exemplo, os 2 exemplos abaixo não funcionam (testei no Chrome e Firefox):

```html
<body background="javascript:alert('body background')">
<img src="javascript:alert('img src')">
```

Isso porque o *browser* tenta carregar as URL's como imagem e falha.

Mas existem outros casos em que um *URI Scheme* do tipo `javascript` funciona. Por exemplo, o exemplo abaixo mostra o `alert` ao carregar o `iframe`:

```html
<body>
  <iframe src="javascript:alert('iframe')"></iframe>
</body>
```

E o exemplo abaixo mostra o `alert` quando o formulário é submetido (não funciona no *snippet* do site, mas testando diretamente no próprio browser, o `alert` foi mostrado):

```html
<form action="javascript:alert('form action')">
    <input type="submit" name="vai">
</form>
```

---

### Por que funciona?

Isso funciona porque, de forma resumida, acontece o seguinte:

- o elemento possui um atributo cujo valor é uma URI qualquer (usando qualquer *URI Scheme* existente): um `form` pode ter uma URI no atributo `action`, um `iframe` pode ter no `src`, um `a` pode ter no `href`, etc...
- esta URI é avaliada quando ocorrer um determinado evento, que varia conforme o elemento: em um `form`, é quando este é submetido, no `iframe`, é no momento em que ele é carregado, em um `a`, é quando este é clicado.
- cada URI tem uma forma de ser avaliada e uma "consequência" (algo que ocorre em seguida):

  - se for uma URL como `http://www.etc...`: se estiver em um `a` faz com que o browser vá para a página, o `form` submete os dados para esta URL, o `iframe` carrega o conteúdo da URL.
  - se for `mailto:fulano@gmail.com`, pode por exemplo abrir o cliente de email que está configurado no browser/SO (geralmente com o campo "To:" já preenchido com o endereço indicado).
  - se for `javascript:código`, o código é executado (o algoritmo para avaliar/executar um *URI scheme* `javascript` é descrito [aqui](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#the-javascript:-url-special-case)).
  - etc... (cada *URI Scheme* tem sua própria maneira de ser avaliado e uma ação que o *browser* toma em seguida)
  - dependendo do elemento, pode ser que a URI não funcione (como é o caso do `img src` citado acima, por exemplo)

---

### Mas faz sentido?

Se faz sentido usar ou não, aí é outra história (mas me parece que o foco da pergunta é mais sobre porque existe, e não necessariamente se faz sentido usar `alert` em um link - embora as outras respostas tenham focado somente neste segundo aspecto).

Talvez um `a` com `javascript` no `href` não faça muito sentido (como já explicado em [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/471916/112052)), mas com outros *URI schemes* faça. Por exemplo, `mailto` ou `tel` em um link, a meu ver, faz todo sentido - inclusive [a MDN diz o seguinte](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attr-href) sobre o atributo `href`:

> *Links are not restricted to HTTP-based URLs — they can use any URL scheme supported by browsers.*
>
> ---
>
> Links não são restritos à URL's HTTP - eles podem usar qualquer *scheme* suportado pelos browsers.

E entre os exemplos de *schemes*, ele cita `tel` e `mailto`, entre outros ([outra página com um exemplo similar](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/address)). Mas a mesma MDN [também diz](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#onclick_events):

> *Anchor elements are often abused as fake buttons by setting their `href` to `#` or `javascript:void(0)` to prevent the page from refreshing, then listening for their click events.*
>
> *These bogus `href` values cause unexpected behavior when copying/dragging links, opening links in a new tab/window, bookmarking, or when JavaScript is loading, errors, or is disabled. They also convey incorrect semantics to assistive technologies, like screen readers.*
>
> *Use a `<button>` instead. In general, you should only use a hyperlink for navigation to a real URL.*
>
> ---
>
> Elementos `a` são frequentemente abusados na forma de botões falsos, setando o `href` para `#` ou `javascript:void(0)` para impedir que a página recarregue, e escutando os eventos de clique.
>
> Esses valores de `href` causam comportamento inesperado ao copiar/arrastar os links, abrindo-os em uma nova aba/janela, adicionando aos favoritos ou quando o JavaScript está carregando, dá erro ou está desabilitado. Isso também dá uma semântica incorreta para tecnologias assistivas, como leitores de tela.
>
> Em vez disso, use um `<button>`. De forma geral, você só deveria usar um link para navegar para uma URL real.

Ou seja, tecnicamente nada impede que se use `javascript:código` em um link, só não é recomendado.

<sup>Se os browsers proibissem tudo que não é recomendado, muita coisa deixaria de funcionar. Mas divago...</sup>

---

### Um pouco de especulação...

Claro que o *browser* até poderia permitir apenas *URL Schemes* que "fazem sentido" e desabilitar o resto, mas pelo que vemos, não foi assim que decidiram fazer.

Mas vamos supor que os *browsers* decidam que não vai ser mais permitido código JavaScript no `href`. Isso *poderia* resolver a questão da semântica e demais problemas citados nas outras respostas, mas apenas parcialmente, pois ainda seria possível fazer isso:

```js
document.querySelector('a').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('vc clicou no link, mas ele não vai pra lugar nenhum');
});
```

```html
<a href="https://www.google.com">Link</a>
```

Ou seja, continua sendo possível fazer um link que não se comporta como um link: a URL do `href` é completamente ignorada e eu só mostro um `alert` (e esse funciona no *snippet* do site).

Claro que ainda sim alguém poderia argumentar que se proibir código no `href`, seria "um problema a menos para se preocupar". Mas pode ser que decidiram que não valia a pena criar uma exceção para fechar apenas uma porta, sendo que todas as outras continuariam abertas (e aqui estou especulando, não sei se alguém chegou de fato a discutir esse assunto ou se simplesmente implementaram o suporte aos *URI Schemes* em todos os atributos que podem receber uma URI válida e pronto).

Meu palpite é que "resolver" isso traria complicações demais que provavelmente não valem a pena, pois como eu impediria o caso acima? Dependendo do elemento e/ou do evento, eu deveria proibir a chamada à `preventDefault`? Ou não deveria nem deixar adicionar o evento de clique? Mas e os outros eventos, como `hover`, `focus`, e [tantos outros](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events)? Mas aí o código daria erro ("estourando" na tela ou no console) ou falharia em silêncio? E isso é só para `a[href]`, eu teria que rever também o comportamento para todos os atributos já citados, que aceitam um *URI Scheme* `javascript`. Quais combinações de elemento/evento "fazem sentido" e quais deveriam ser "proibidas"?

Então me parece que é "melhor" deixar que se aceite JavaScript no `href`, e quem cria as páginas que se preocupe em não (ab)usar.

---

Enfim, resumindo é isso: existe porque alguém criou, e ainda funciona porque não parece haver uma justificativa "boa o bastante" para deixar de funcionar.

Comment: Em links faz um pouco de sentido se usado com `windows.open`, mas, hoje, é mais raro seu uso, antigamente talvez fosse mais usado pra abrir chats ou algo assim (mas sou muito novo pra saber)

Comment: @Costamilam Isso também é discutível. Se o link deve abrir em outra janela, por que não usar o atributo `target`? Tudo bem que ele pode acabar abrindo outra aba e não tem como controlar, e `window.open` força a abertura de outra janela, mas aí cai no que eu citei na resposta: se não é para se comportar como um link, talvez devesse ser um botão ou outra coisa. Mas os browsers não impedem porque eles costumam ser bem permissivos com tudo (HTML mal formado que o diga), então cabe a nós evitar abusar dessas coisas :-)

Comment: Sim, por isso disse "um pouco". Se os navegadores permitem até código XHTML, HTML4 e pequenos blocos incompletos, fora as APIs nativas consideradas obsoletas e que ainda funcionam, seria até estranho não permitir isso

Comment: @hkotsubo, boa respota! eu entendi o seu ponto de vista e me deu uma nova perspectiva, talvez se cada coisa que não fizesse sentido deixasse de funcionar, os códigos e programas que nós criamos, talvez não funcionasse como esperado, melhor deixar às coisas como está para não gerar problemas ou resultados inconvenientes.

Answer (score 3):

No seu caso não faz sentido, pois não é semântico, e vai causar um ***problema de acessibilidade e de SEO***. Links são para navegação, dentro ou fora da página, e não para alertas.

Segunda a Mozilla:

> **href:**
>  A URL para a qual o hiperlink aponta. Links não se restrigem a URLs baseadas no protocolo HTTP — eles podem utilizar
> qualquer tipo de URL suportado pelos browsers:
>
> - Seções de página com fragmentos URL
> - Pedaços de arquivos de mídia com fragmentos da própria mídia
> - Números de telefone com tel: URLs
> - Email addresses with(Endereço de email com) mailto: URLs
> - Alguns navegadores talvez não aguentem certos arranjos em URL, para    isso os websites fazem uso do registerProtocolHandler()

Fonte: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attr-href

E segundo a própria W3C sobre o `href`

> This attribute specifies the location of a Web resource, thus defining a link between the current element (the source anchor) and the destination anchor defined by this attribute.

---

**Problemas de UX**

Mas o ponto principal mesmo é a acessibilidade e não se você "pode" ou não usar JS no link. Você tem que pensar na **UX**, você já clicou em um Link e viu um Alert aparecer? Seria algo muito inusitado concorda, pois é um comportamento que não se espera de um link.

Outra coisa é em relação aos ***Screen Readers*** (leitores de tela), o que será que vai acontecer quando o Leitor de Tela falar para o Usuário que ele está em um link, aí ele clica e dá um Alerta... É algo sem sentido semântico.

---

**Problemas de SEO** (atualização em 07/01/2020)

Apesar de no exemplo da pergunta o `script` estar no `href`, apenas estou reiterando que mesmo se usar a tag  sem o href também causaria problemas, principalmente relacionados a rastreabilidade dos motores de busca, afetando diretamente o seu SEO. Veja que isso é errado e não deve ser usado `<a onclick="goto('https://example.com')">`

Veja que o report do Lighthouse acura problema em um `<a>` sem `href`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Fonte: https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/guidelines/links-crawlable?visit_id=637456205254179997-1941812978&rd=1

Comment: Sim! é justamente este caso da minha pergunta. O que eu queria saber é porque os scripts podem ser executados nos links deve haver algum motivo se não o criadouro nem tinha implementado isso.

Comment: @felipecardozo a grosso modo não é pq vc pode que vc deve. Funcionar funciona, mas não é o ideal pelos motivos descritos na resposta

Answer (score 0):

Entendo sua dúvida, mas acredito que essa seja uma das muitas soluções que já foram muito populares em anos atrás e que estão sendo descontinuadas. Não se recomenda o uso do método `alert()` a não ser que seja para validações de formulários ou bloqueio de ações do browser. Em todo caso, tem-se como um consenso de boa prática o uso do Document Object Model (DOM) para exibição em documento HTML.

```js
const showAlert = document.getElementById("showTheAlert");

showAlert.onclick = function() {

  alert("Alert com DOM!!!");
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>
  <input id="showTheAlert" type="button" value="Display alert box">

  <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```