# Qual é a diferença entre "javascript:void(0)" e apenas "void(0)" ao definir o onclick no HTML?

Tags: javascript, onclick

Ao utilizar o PHPStorm, percebi um *warning* apontando para o código onde fiz `onclick="javascript:void(0)"`, recomendando que deixasse apenas `onclick="void(0)"`.

Essa é uma prática recomendada e válida? Achei bem estranho, pois não encontrei nada na internet referente a isso.

Comment: Editei a pergunta para simplificá-la, deixá-la sucinta e direta ao ponto. Também editei o título para descrever fielmente a sua dúvida.

Comment: Perfeito, exatamente isso que eu queria. Obrigado

Comment: Relacionado: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/471899/112052

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quando avaliados como JavaScript, os dois códigos farão a mesma coisa: avaliar para `undefined` (que é o que o operador `void` faz). Na prática, o efeito disso é o mesmo: nada. A diferença entre os dois casos é meramente sintática.

Conforme expliquei [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/483694/69296), todo código colocado dentro de um *attribute event listener* é interpretado como código JavaScript normalmente (com algumas diferenças, já explicadas na pergunta).

Desse modo, se você quiser comparar essas duas sequências inseridas em um atributo de evento como `onclick`, deverá compará-las como código JavaScript. Para isso, podemos comparar a árvore sintática ([AST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree)) dos dois. Utilizei o [AST explorer](https://astexplorer.net) para chegar nos resultados que deixarei ao final da pergunta como anexo.

---

Quando avaliado como JavaScript, `javascript:void(0)` é basicamente composto  por uma expressão (`void(0)`) identificada pelo *label* `javascript`. O *label* não é um recurso muito comum de ser encontrado em código JavaScript visto que seu uso é decerto raro. A [documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label) explica como funciona.

Se estiver falando de JavaScript, `void(0)` e `javascript:void(0)` não possuem diferenças em questão de efeito, apenas sintática, como se pode verificar no anexo ao final da resposta. É por isso que o *linter* pede para que se remova o *label* `javascript` — como a sequência no atributo `onclick` denota um código JavaScript, o *label* nada está fazendo nesse  caso.

Por conta disso, presumo ter havido uma confusão. Embora, em atributos de evento (tais como `onclick`), o prefixo `javascript:` ser sintaticamente correto (e útil, em alguns casos), quando a sequência é interpretada como um *link*, o prefixo `javascript:` é utilizado (e necessário) para denotar que o link trata-se de um código JavaScript.

Desse modo, tratando-se do atributo `href` de elementos `<a>`, há diferença entre `javascript:void(0)` e `void(0)`, uma vez que:

- `<a href="javascript:void(0)"> ... </a>` indica uma âncora que contém um link que executa código JavaScript (nesse caso, `void(0)`). Portanto, trata-se de um endereço válido.
- `<a href="void(0)"> ... </a>` indica uma âncora que contém um link inválido. `void(0)` não é um URL válido.

---

Em suma, a diferença existe de acordo com a forma como `javascript:void(0)` e `void(0)` são interpretados:

- Se forem interpretados como JavaScript (o que ocorre em atributos de evento como `onclick`), a diferença é meramente sintática, já que o efeito é o mesmo.
- Se forem interpretados como um URL (o que ocorre, por exemplo, no atributo `href` de um elemento `<a>`), `javascript:void(0)` é um *link* válido que denota a avaliação do JavaScript `void(0)`, enquanto `void(0)` é um *link* inválido que, portanto, não fará nada.

---

## Anexo: Diferença sintática de código JavaScript

#### Para `javascript:void(0)`

```
{
  "type": "Program",
  "start": 0,
  "end": 18,
  "body": [
    {
      "type": "LabeledStatement",
      "start": 0,
      "end": 18,
      "body": {
        "type": "ExpressionStatement",
        "start": 11,
        "end": 18,
        "expression": {
          "type": "UnaryExpression",
          "start": 11,
          "end": 18,
          "operator": "void",
          "prefix": true,
          "argument": {
            "type": "Literal",
            "start": 16,
            "end": 17,
            "value": 0,
            "raw": "0"
          }
        }
      },
      "label": {
        "type": "Identifier",
        "start": 0,
        "end": 10,
        "name": "javascript"
      }
    }
  ],
  "sourceType": "module"
}
```

Veja que se trata de uma expressão etiquetada com o *label* `javascript`.

## Para `void(0)`

```
{
  "type": "Program",
  "start": 0,
  "end": 7,
  "body": [
    {
      "type": "ExpressionStatement",
      "start": 0,
      "end": 7,
      "expression": {
        "type": "UnaryExpression",
        "start": 0,
        "end": 7,
        "operator": "void",
        "prefix": true,
        "argument": {
          "type": "Literal",
          "start": 5,
          "end": 6,
          "value": 0,
          "raw": "0"
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "sourceType": "module"
}
```

Veja que se trata apenas de uma expressão.

Comment: É algo difícil de se explicar já que se tratam de dois modos de avaliação diferentes (que ocorrem quando a sequência é interpretada como URI ou código JavaScript). Mais tarde tento revisar o texto para tentar deixá-lo um pouco mais claro. Português é difícil! ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Ficou muito claro e muito bem explicado. Eu não sabia que o label "javascript" podia ser omitido da propriedade "onclick". Muito obrigado pela resposta!

Comment: @EvandroPH, o label nesse caso nem faz muito sentido. É mais uma adição comum porque muita gente coloca o `javascript:void(0)` no `href` de um `<a>`, aí "pega" o hábito e o leva para o `onclick`. No que tange ao JavaScript, _labels_ são úteis, geralmente, em laços de repetição aninhados. Fora isso, raramente há um caso de uso em que realmente sejam úteis. :)

Comment: @EvandroPH o label não faz parte do onClick e não é a mesma coisa do javascript: em `href="javascript:...."`... o label ali no onClick poderia ter qualquer nome como `onclick="foobar:alert(1)"` que vai funcionar. O label é uma parte da linguagem que você pode dar o "nome" que desejar, na verdade `onclick="javascript:...."` é provavelmente um equivoco de alguém se confundiu e fez algo que deveria ser para o href em onclick. Sobre: [**label**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label), ele é usado com loops (é vagamente semelhante ao "goto").