# Qual diferença entre javascript:void(0) e javascript:{}

Tags: javascript

Ao utilizar ***links* cegos**, dentro da *tag* `href`, as duas formas abaixo são aceitas pelo JavaScript:

1º método:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)">Link cego</a>
```

2º método:

```
<a href="javascript:{}">Link cego</a>
```

**Mas qual a diferença? Qual seria a forma correta?**

Obs.: ao passar o mouse sobre o referido *link*, a mensagem abaixo é exibida na barra de status do navegador¹:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Por que não seria seguro?**

¹ *Navegador Brave: Version 1.42.88 Chromium: 104.0.5112.81 (Official Build) (64-bit)*

Comment: Relacionado: [Qual é a diferença entre "javascript:void(0)" e apenas "void(0)" ao definir o onclick no HTML?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/500582/112052)

Comment: Provavelmente o que exibe isso é algum "plugin", não o navegador em si, nos navegadores que usei nenhum apresentou tal problema.

Comment: O unsafe: provavelmente é do Angular, [atualizei a resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/561904/3635).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nenhuma das duas fazem nada, e você pode escrever scripts que não fazem nada, como exemplo:

```
<script>
{}
</script>
```

E poderia ser:

```
<script>
void 0
</script>
```

Note que void é uma operador e não uma função, logo fazer isso `void 1 === 1`, seria o mesmo que `void(1) === 1`, vai retornar false, já que o operador `void` sempre retorna `undefined`.

Só porque ambas não executam nada da forma que foram chamadas não que dizer que sejam a mesma coisa, você poderia fazer algo como:

```html
<script>
function foo() {}
</script>

<a href="javascript:foo()">Teste</a>
```

Que teria o mesmo efeito aparente, claro que para o motor JavaScript do navegador (também NodeJS, Deno, Burn, etc) são executadas coisas diferentes, mesmo que estejam vazias.

Existem muitos *"protocolos"* em páginas web, como `blob:` para acessar URLs geradas por `URL.createObjectURL()`, `tel:`, `mailto:` e você poderia até registrar mais algumas URLs com [`navigator.registerProtocolHandler()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/registerProtocolHandler), mas isso seria falar de muitas coisas além, a questão é que `javascript:` no `href=""` será usado para seus scripts, note que o `{}` é usado para escopos, é chamado de `block`, como expliquei em [JavaScript mudou suas regras sobre o que é falso ou verdadeiro?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/484654/3635), então ao executar `href="javascript:{}"` não está sendo usado para nada, mas o uso natural seria para isolar escopos, que poderia ser útil como alternativa ao IIFE (immediately invoked function expression):

```js
{
   let foo = 0;
}

console.log(foo); // Causará "Uncaught ReferenceError: foo is not defined"
```

---

### Angular e o prefixo unsafe:

O prefixo `unsafe:` costuma ser adicionado pelo framework Angular, justamente por questão de segurança (ou tentativa), ou algum framework baseado em Angular (como Ionic), ele adiciona propositalmente o prefixo `unsafe:` para induzir o usuário a evitar usar JavaScript diretamente em Links, e provavelmente o Angular deve ter um allow-list que considera que `javascript:void(0)` como seguro e não adiciona prefixo, mas não consegue analisar variações, como `javascript:{}`.

Se não for Angular ou framework, pode ser algum plugin. De qualquer forma, adicionar o prefixo `unsafe:` não é nativo de nenhum navegador comum.

Comment: Guilherme, e porque não é seguro (inclui a dúvida na edição)?

Comment: @lucasbento em que navegador ou plugin informa isso? Pois no Chrome e Firefox aqui não é exibido tal informação, isso não me parece regra de HTML ou JavaScript, mas sim de algo sobre dicas de ferramentas como "LightHouse".

Comment: Incluí a informação do navegador na pergunta.

Comment: @lucasbento você está usando Angular, ou algum framework baseado em Angular (como Ionic), ele adiciona propositalmente o prefixo `unsafe:` para induzir o usuário a evitar usar JavaScript diretamente em Links, e provavelmente o Angular deve ter um allow-list que considera que `javascript:void(0)` é OK, mas não consegue analisar variações, como `javascript:{}` ... **[editado]** Editei a resposta, veja se confere com o seu cenário.